# Javascript collision engine that runs well with hundreds(possibly thousands) of collision checks?

Tags: javascript, performance, collision-detection

I am testing out making a powder-based physics engine, and I have quickly run into a problem: there are too many collision checks for my computer to load after about 150 particles. I need a physics engine that will be able to load many more collisions than that, possibly in the thousands, and some of these particles will do multiple collision checks. All the particles are being checked for a collision with all the other particles at once, and they are all 2x2 squares. Any suggestions for a better collision system?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
var powder = {};
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var click = false;
var select = 0;
var types = {
  0: "green",
  1: "blue",
  2: "brown",
  3: "grey"
}
document.onmousemove = function(mouse) {
  mouseX = mouse.clientX - document.getElementById('c').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  mouseY = mouse.clientY - document.getElementById('c').getBoundingClientRect().top;
};

function newPowder(x, y, type, id) {
  var temp = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: type,
    checked: false,
  };
  powder[id] = temp;
};

function choose(a, b) {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return a
  } else {
    return b
  }
}
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 40) { //Down
    select--;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //Up
    select++;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 32) { //space
    click = true;
  };
  if (select > 3) {
    select = 3;
  } else
  if (select < 1) {
    select = 0
  };
}
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    click = false
  };
};
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  if (click) {
    newPowder(Math.round(mouseX / 2) * 2, Math.round(mouseY / 2) * 2, select, Math.random() * 50);
  };
  for (var key in powder) {
    var toContinue = false;
    drawDot(powder[key].x, powder[key].y, types[powder[key].type])
    if (powder[key].type == 3) {
      continue
    }
    if (powder[key].onGround == false) {
      for (var key2 in powder) {
        if (getDistanceBetweenEntity(powder[key], powder[key2]) < 3) {
          if (collisionCheck(powder[key2].x, powder[key2].y, 2, 2, powder[key].x, powder[key].y + 2, 2, 2)) {
            powder[key].onGround = true
            if (powder[key2].type == 2 && !powder[key].checked) {
              powder[key].checked = true;
              powder[key].x += choose(choose(2, -2), 0);
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
    if (toContinue) {
      continue;
    }
    if (powder[key].x > 500 || powder[key].y > 500) {
      delete powder[key];
      continue;
    }

    if (!powder[key].onGround) {
      powder[key].y += 2;
      checked = false;
    } else if (powder[key].type == 1) {
      powder[key].x += choose(2, -2);
    }
    powder[key].onGround = false;
  };
}, 0);

function rectangleContainsPoint(x1, y1, width, height, x, y) {
  if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return (x >= x1 && x <= x1 + width && y >= y1 && y <= y1 + height);
};

function drawDot(x, y, color) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);
  ctx.restore();
}

function collisionCheck(x1, y1, width1, height1, x2, y2, width2, height2) {
  if (x1 < x2 + width2 && x1 + width1 > x2 && y1 < y2 + height2 && height1 + y1 > y2) {
    return true;
  };
};
getDistanceBetweenEntity = function(entity1, entity2) {
  var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
  var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
  return Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="500px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid #000" onclick="click = true"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Up and Down arrows to change particle type. Space to spawn particles.

Comment: http://www.stefanom.org/bh-tree/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally a quadratic complexity algorithm isn't going to scale very well with more particles where you check for collision of every particle against every other particle. You want to reduce the search time per particle from linear to logarithmic or better.

Acceleration structures useful here could be a fixed grid or a quad tree or K-d tree.

Instead of checking for a particle collision against every other particle, put your particles into a grid structure or hierarchy (quad tree).

For the grid, simply check the particles residing in the same grid cell(s) as the particle you are testing for collision (there could be multiple if the particle has a non-zero size).

The quad tree is simply an extension of this concept with an "adaptive" grid that forms a hierarchy. The K-d tree is similar, except it's a binary tree instead of a 4-ary tree which cycles between X/Y partitions of the search space, and doesn't have to subdivide evenly (however, it is typically the most expensive to construct among these three).

The tricky part here is that when your data is very dynamic, as in this case, you have to be able to build and update the structure fast enough. So sometimes a simpler structure like the fixed grid can work better here than the quad tree since it's easier to build that more quickly even though it provides lower-quality spatial queries.

In any case, any kind of accelerator here should make your algorithm scale a whole lot better, and I would suggest the fixed grid for starters, and the quad tree if you need even faster collision queries in exchange for increased time building and updating the accelerator.

Also given the nature of your program so far where the particles are only affected by gravity in a straight downward fashion, an even simpler way than the above methods is to sort your particles by their X position (can use radix sort to do this in linear time). Then you can do a binary search to find which particles are first in the X proximity to narrow the number of tests you are performing to logarithmic. This is potentially even worse than the fixed grid in terms of search query since it has pathological cases where all particles could be in the same X position (a fixed grid would account for both X and Y), but it's a quick way to do it.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I've checked out a few of the structures and I didn't understand what they are, what they do, and how you use them. They all seem really complex and I'm not quite at that level of programming.

Comment: If you imagine for a simple example where your screen is split in two halves down a vertical diving line, then you have a list of two "cells". The elements to the left of the line could be in one cell (list), the elements to the right of the center can be in the other cell (you can use an array of two lists). When you have this, then when you want to test a particle on the left side of the screen to see if it collides with others, you only need to check those particles that are also on the left side of the screen (don't need to check those on the right side).

Comment: s/diving/dividing. These data structures are basically just this idea extended to where the screen can consist of more than two cells (as many as you want). But just this uber-simple example where your screen is split in half (and into two separate particle lists) means you potentially halve the number of particles you have to test per particle on average.

Comment: Of course in this simple example, if a particle is right smack on the center of the line and straddling both sides of the screen, then you have to check both cell lists (the left cell and right cell) as the particle would belong in both cells. But particles that are completely to the left or to the right of the line do not, and only have to check one of the two lists. If you can understand this basic idea, then all of these fancy data structures are just extending upon this fundamental idea.

Answer (score -1):

First (for in array) is much slower than for (var i = 0; i < array.length i++);

Anyway you are doing brute force pair collision detection. This is never going to be efficient, you need an algorithm to calculate only "nearby" particles each step. Basically if a pair is found to be far away from each other, they are not calculated on the next X steps, where X = distance / maxSpeed (speed of light in your world).

Comment: I already have something along those lines(I think). If a particle is a certain distance from the particle in question, it will not check a collision. It will only check a maximum distance of 3px, or the adjacent areas. 

`if (getDistanceBetweenEntity(powder[key], powder[key2]) < 3) [do collision check]`

Comment: That's a micro optimization (and I'm not sure it actually helps to compute the square root vector distance between points to avoid a rectangle collision check), but your algorithm is still brute force pairwise collision detection. If you have to even loop through every single particle against potentially every other, then it's brute force. It's like a bubble sort in that case -- you want to use something a bit more algorithmically efficient first, like a quicksort or even merge sort, and then micro-optimize. Otherwise it's going to get explosively slower the more particles you have.

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla: That `getDistanceBetweenEntity()` function is expensive because it uses `sqrt()` and multiply. For just roughly estimating distance it's cheaper to just calculate the manhattan distance: `vx+vy`.